# Excess elements in scalar initializer for struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a struct called `result` that has the following definition:

```
struct result {
void** elements;
size_t n_elements;
};
```

But when I try to initialise it with the following properties `{ NULL, 0 }` I receive the following warning:

```
warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
struct result * result_elements = { NULL, 0 };
```

Is this an error because it's expecting a 2D array? If so, I thought NULL was permissible?

Cheers :)

Comment: `struct result * result_elements` is a pointer.

Comment: You're trying to initialize a pointer with a structure value. Perhaps you mean `struct result * result_elements = &(struct result){ NULL, 0 };` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pointer

```
struct result * result_elements /**/;
```

You try to initialise it with

```
{ NULL, 0 }
```

You could initialise it e.g. with a scalar initialiser like

```
NULL
```

You could initialise a separate (non-pointer) variable with your non-scalar initialiser, e.g.

```
struct result avariable = { NULL, 0 };
```

And then you could initialise your pointer like

```
struct result * result_elements = &avariable;
```

Comment: Or `&(struct result){NULL, 0}`

Comment: Ajay's solution seems to return a compilation error. "error: taking the address of a temporary object of type 'struct result' [-Waddress-of-temporary]"